# If condition for elements within set

Tags: r, if-statement

I am working within a `for` loop with index `j in 1:N` and I also have a sample `v <- sample(1:N,n,F)`. I'm looking for some sort of *if else* statement that works this way:

```
for(j in 1:N){
  if(j in v){
      ...
  }else{ ... }
```

The problem with this is that `if` doesn't work with `in`. Also I need to work with `j` in a chronological way therefore I can't work with two different loops, one for `j in 1:N` and another for `j in v`.

Comment: Are you looking for `%in%` ? E.g. `1 %in% 1:3`

Comment: What do you want to inside `if{...}` `else{...}` blocks. Maybe you don't need `if`/`else` at all. Can you give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and show expected output for it?

Comment: Yes @thelatemail That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks and sorry for the dumb question.